# C# : IF ELSE replacement

Tags: c#, if-statement, design-patterns, switch-statement, conditional-operator

In the application there are 3 methods,in the methods there are update/insert queries. Methods are dependent on each other. If first method runs successfully, second is called; second runs successfully - third is called.

Here is code I have written

DataContext Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Dapper;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace DataAccessEntity.DbContext
{
    public class DataContext
    {
        static SqlConnection con;
        static SqlTransaction tran;
        
        public static SqlTransaction StartTransaction()
        {
            return con.BeginTransaction();
        }
        public static void RollBackTransaction()
        {
            tran.Rollback();
        }
        public static void CommitTransaction()
        {
            tran.Commit();
        }
        public static int ExecuteSql(string sql,string connectionstring,DynamicParameters param)
        {
            int result = 0;
            try
            {
                using (con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
                {
                    if (con.State.Equals(ConnectionState.Closed))
                        con.Open();
                            tran = StartTransaction();
                            result = 
                           con.Execute(sql,null,tran,0,CommandType.Text);
                            CommitTransaction();
                        con.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                RollBackTransaction();
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
            
            return result;
        }
        public static DataTable ExecuteToDataTable(string sql, string connectionstring, DynamicParameters param, SqlTransaction tran)
        {
            DataTable dt = null;
            using (con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
            {
                if (con.State.Equals(ConnectionState.Closed))
                    con.Open();
                var result = con.ExecuteReader(sql, null, null, 0, CommandType.Text);
                dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(result);
                con.Close();
            }
            return dt;
        }
    }
}
```

DataAccessEntity

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using DataAccessEntity.DbContext;

namespace DataAccessEntity
{
    public class CountryDE
    {
        static string connectionstring;
        public static int UpdateCountry(IConfiguration _iconfiguration)
        {
            try
            {
                connectionstring = _iconfiguration.GetConnectionString("Default");
                string sql = "Update tb_country set country='Spain' where id=1;Update tb_country set country='USA' where id=2;Update tb_country set country='USA' where id=13;Update tb_country set country='USA' where id=14;Update tb_country set country='USA' where id=15;Update tb_country set country='USA' where id=16";
                int result = DataContext.ExecuteSql(sql, connectionstring, null);
                return result;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        public static int AddCountries(IConfiguration _iconfiguration)
        {
            try
            {
                connectionstring = _iconfiguration.GetConnectionString("Default");
                string sql = "insert into tb_country(country,active) values ('Argentina',1)";
                int result = DataContext.ExecuteSql(sql, connectionstring, null);
                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        public static DataTable GetCountry(IConfiguration _iconfiguration)
        {
            try
            {
                connectionstring = _iconfiguration.GetConnectionString("Default");
                string sql = "Select id,country,active from tb_country";
                DataTable dt = DataContext.ExecuteToDataTable(sql, connectionstring, null, null);
                return dt;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
}
    }
}
```

BusinessEntity

```
using System;
using DataAccessEntity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using UtilityEntity;
using System.Data;
using System.Reflection;

namespace BusinessEntity
{
    public class CountryBE
    {
        public static int UpdateCountry(IConfiguration _iconfiguration)
        {
            int result = 0;
            try
            {
                Logger.LogMessage(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name + "" + "Started");
                result = CountryDE.UpdateCountry(_iconfiguration);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.LogException(ex.Message);
            }
            return result;
        }

        public static int AddCountries(IConfiguration _iconfiguration)
        {
            int result = 0;
            try
            {
                Logger.LogMessage(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name + "" + "Started");
                result = CountryDE.AddCountries(_iconfiguration);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.LogException(ex.Message);
            }
            return result;
        }

        public static DataTable GetCountry(IConfiguration _iconfiguration)
        {
            try
            {
                Logger.LogMessage(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name + "" + "Started");
                DataTable dt = CountryDE.GetCountry(_iconfiguration);
                return dt;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Main Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.IO;
using DataModelEntity;
using UtilityEntity;
using BusinessEntity;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using NLog.Extensions.Logging;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        private static IConfiguration _iconfiguration;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GetAppSettingsFile();
            var servicesProvider = BuildDi(_iconfiguration);

            using(servicesProvider as IDisposable)
            {
                servicesProvider.GetRequiredService<Logger>();
            }
            UpdateCountries();
            
        }

        public static IServiceProvider BuildDi(IConfiguration config)
        {
            return new ServiceCollection()
                .AddTransient<Logger>().
                AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
                {
                    loggingBuilder.ClearProviders();
                    loggingBuilder.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Information);
                    loggingBuilder.AddNLog(config);
                }).BuildServiceProvider();
        }
        static void GetAppSettingsFile()
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                                 .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                                 .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
            _iconfiguration = builder.Build();
        }

        

        static void UpdateCountries()
        {
            int result = CountryBE.UpdateCountry(_iconfiguration);
             
            if(result > 0)
            {
                AddCountries();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not Updated");
            }
        }

        static void AddCountries()
        {
            int result = CountryBE.AddCountries(_iconfiguration);
             
            if(result > 0)
            {
                GetCountryDetails();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not Updated");
            }
        }

        static void GetCountryDetails()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Get Countries");
            DataTable dt = CountryBE.GetCountry(_iconfiguration);
            foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(dr["country"].ToString());
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

As in Program.cs if else is used,
I want to write this same code without using if statement, switch case or ternary operators. please guide me on how to do this.

Comment: What is the reason for not wanting to use `if`, `switch`, or ternary ops?

Comment: What happens if one doesn't finish successfully? do you throw an exception?, if so you can create another function that calls them one by one, wrapped in a `try ... catch` block.

Comment: You can try returning `bool` in each method (`true` if method succeeds) and then combine them with `&&`: `bool result = method1() && method2() && ..&& method5();`

Answer (score 2):

I would first change the method signatures to return `result`.

You can then declare and array `methods` of `Func<int>` and initialize it to Method1, Method2, ...Methodn

You then just need a loop:

```
foreach (method in methods) {
    if (method() == 0)
        break; // or any other action.
}
```

Code can be added to handle something going wrong.

Comment: Your answer contains an `if` statement; OP does not want?

Comment: @CaiusJard OP does not want to repeat same code. At least as I understood it.

Comment: Yes I do not want to repat the same code. As same code is repeated code is becoming unreadable. there are total 20 methods,so 20 times I am writing if else.

Comment: Did you try the proposed solution?

Comment: I have edited the question again,kindly go through the same and let me know exactly how to implement this in the code edited.

Answer (score 2):

@Tarik's answer is simple and does the job, I'd go with that.

There are other ways though.
You could, for example, create a [Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=net-5.0) for each method, and use one of the multiple options that c# TPL provides for that (for example, [continuations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/chaining-tasks-by-using-continuation-tasks))

Another simple thing, would be to make use of the [short-circuit conditional operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#conditional-logical-and-operator-), like this:

```
return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery1() > 0
    && cmd.ExecuteNonQuery2() > 0
    && cmd.ExecuteNonQuery3() > 0
    && cmd.ExecuteNonQuery4() > 0;
```

Comment: Does the job elegantly. The drawback is that it will fail silently.

Answer (score 0):

To give you another idea how things can be done, I'd suggest you looking into
[Functional Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming)
You can find similar approach in my [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69308503/what-to-do-when-all-methods-start-with-the-same-condition/69311094#69311094) to a similar problem.
Basically what you can do is introduce a method for the if statement and reuse the method where needed. That way you will not have if statements as you wanted and will have the logic written in one single place. For example you can have a method like this:

```
 private static bool ExecuteIfTrue(this bool nonQueryResult, Func<int> nonQueryAction, Action actionToInvoke)
 {
     if (nonQueryResult && nonQueryAction() > 0)
     {
         actionToInvoke();
         return true;
     }

     return false;
 }
```

And then chain your methods w/o if statements in a functional programming style:

```
var initialResult = ExecuteNonQuery() > 0;
initialResult.ExecuteIfTrue(ExecuteNonQuery, Method1)
   .ExecuteIfTrue(ExecuteNonQuery, Method2)
   .ExecuteIfTrue(ExecuteNonQuery, Method3)
// ......
   ;
```

Comment: The solution is working. Thanks for the answer,but kindly guide me if design pattern can be use in the same.. I have also edited the code in the question i asked

Comment: @aniketnarvankar To be honest, the question was easier to understand & much more compact before, yet the idea remained the same. As I understand, you want to improve the part of calling `UpdateCountries` method. With my proposed solution, it will look smth like: `(CountryBE.UpdateCountry(_iconfiguration) > 0).ExecuteIfTrue(CountryBE.AddCountries(_iconfiguration), AddCountries).ExecuteIfTrue(CountryBE.AddCountries(_iconfiguration), GetCountryDetails)`.

Comment: But since the signature of initial methods differ from the signature of the methods in the update question, you will get compilation errors. You will have to modify ExecuteIfTrue to correspond to the new needs. I hope this gives you more clarity on your question.

Comment: yes the solution has worked

Comment: Excellent  Happy to contribute :)