# What to do when all methods start with the same condition

Tags: design-patterns

In a class, all my methods start with the same *if*

```
if (locked)
    return;
```

Is there a design pattern to use in these situations? There has to be a better way than write the same 2 lines in like 8 methods.

Comment: if the language you're using supports AOP and custom annotations/attributes you might create one. Which language are you using?

Comment: @ddfra i'm using C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's one approach that comes to my mind, it is using [Functional Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming)

One of ideas behind it is reducing code duplications & reusing common structures in functional programming style.

In your case, I have come up with the following extension method:

```
private static void ExecuteOnFalse(this bool condition, Action actionToInvokeOnFalse)
{
    if (condition) return !condition;
    actionToInvokeOnFalse.Invoke();
    return !condition;
}
```

Let's say the main code that you want to execute after the check is this:

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    // Doing something here
}
```

Then, you can replace your code with the following one:

```
locked.ExecuteOnFalse(DoSomething);
```

And the beauty of the functional programming comes with chaining your methods. You can have different modification of the "ExecuteOnFalse" method, one returning bool & accepting Func as the main action. Then you can chain that method and use it this way:

```
locked.ExecuteOnFalse(DoSomething).ExecuteOnFalse(DoSomethingElse);
```

I'd recommend reading [Functional Programming with C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1617293954). It gives good understanding of Functional Programming and brings good examples. In the beginning of the book they replace regular using() {} structure with the functional approach.

Hope this answer gives you some ideas.